# Xamarin Forms - Add Activity Indicator in the toolbar (Right Side)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

How can i set an activity indicator in my Xamarin Forms app toolbar ?

I set  IsBusy=true;  in my page and its onAppearing() function but nothing happens .

```
public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        /*ToolbarItem x = new ToolbarItem();
        x.Name = "Save";
        x.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary;
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(x);*/

        IsBusy = true;
    }

protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        IsBusy = true;

    }
```

I have a toolbar item on the right side but i want it replaced with an activity indicator when something is loading .

I tried isBusy = true without the toolbar item but nothing happens either ...

Any idea how to implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

For android version 4.x (Jellybean & kitkat) will show activity indicator in toolbar right side. after that from lollipop onwards i.e android version 5.x it will not show.